# Displaying the accesskey keyboard shortcuts in Chrome (Mac)

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, accessibility

I'm wondering if it's possible in Google Chrome (Mac) to display all the available "accesskey" keyboard shortcuts for a web page. What I would like to achieve is something like [this for Firefox](http://blog.andrewbeacock.com/2007/06/firefox-hack-to-display-accesskey.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now. See the [Display Access Keys](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/display-access-keys/gpicedcgegaokienkdbbcagodgacpbpd) extension.

(I took the css from the article you linked to an slapped it into a chrome extension package)

Comment: This displays an extension "Text into Multiple Columns", not the one above anymore.

Comment: That's another one of my extensions... not sure what happened to the Display Access Keys extension.

Comment: I've updated the extension and the link in my answer

Comment: It would be good to display them only on request, e.g. when clicking on the extension's icon.

Comment: Nice idea. I won't likely get to that soon - but feel free to fork the code from [my github repo](https://github.com/dougharris/display-access-keys) and submit a pull request.